# Python autocompletion comparable to IPython Notebook for Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know of anything comparable?  I am currently using Anaconda for linting and autocompletion, but it is nowhere near as good as the IPython Notebook autocompletion.

Comment: Switch to emacs, problem solved.

Comment: @PatrickCollins doesn't emacs have a pretty steep learning curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package SublimeCodeIntel is the best I've seen in Sublime for Python autocompletion. It's available through Package Control or [on github.](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same concern when moving from Jupyter Notebook to Sublime Text, and tried Anaconda's autocomplete, which is far worse than Jupyter's.

But after trying SublimeCodeIntel, all problems solved! It is almost same as VSCode's auto-complete and code tips.